# Flutter Kotlin Gradle Pluging Update

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, visual-studio-code

In the new version of Flutter (2.9.1) while running debug process an error occurs. Says "Update Kotlin Gradle plugin to newest version" but my gradle version already upgraded..

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: The value of `ext.kotlin_version` should be a real version (1.6.10) and not `<latest-version>`.

Comment: Deleted my project and created again. That fixed my problem.